# onReceive not being called during device boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am currently learning how to create apps for Android devices and have hit a bit of a snag. The exercise I am currently working on involves broadcasts intents. The specific issue I am having is that when I boot up my device there should be a log message stating that the broadcast intent was received and the alarm for my app should restarted. Unfortunately neither of these things occur as it seems my onReceive method is never called upon booting. As far as I can tell my code is exactly as it should be. I have included my manifest file as well as my receiver class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PhotoGalleryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".PollService"/>

        <receiver android:name="com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery.StartupReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

StartupReceiver.java

```
   package com.bignerdranch.android.photogallery;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * Created by Danny Wayne on 8/16/2016.
     */
    public class StartupReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private static final String TAG = "StartupReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received broadcast intent: " + intent.getAction());

            boolean isOn = QueryPreferences.isAlarmOn(context);
            PollService.setServiceAlarm(context, isOn);
        }

   }
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you run your `Activity` at least once after installation before rebooting? Did you wait a minute or two to give the Receiver a chance to run? It's probably not going to happen as soon as the home screen shows.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. In addition to the log message and alarm waking up, the "Start Polling" menu item should remain toggled when the app is started after the boot as it's Boolean state is pulled from the shared preference. However, when restarting the app the menu item has returned to the off position.

Comment: The posted code is itself correct. Are you sure you're not just missing the log print, maybe due to filtering, or the just the sheer volume of log entries? You might consider something more noticeable for testing, like issuing a `Notification` directly from the Receiver. Also, if you're testing on a device, check if it has any non-standard security settings/options, that may be restricting the boot broadcast from your app. I know some brands, like Xiaomi, have additional settings like that.

Comment: That fixed it sir! There was indeed a restriction prevent any downloaded apps from running in the back ground. Thank you for your help!